# Ruby-Cucumber remove all parameters from feature file

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I have huge feature file and I would like to remove all the parameter from the feature file. I'm using RubyMine IDE.

Comment: parameters ? Eg?

Comment: For example :  
Given x "test"
when y "test2"
then z "test3"

I would like to remove test1,test2 and test3